# HTML Absolute Links Acting Relative

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-email

When I tried to view an HTML email, it didn't work and thought the following link was an absolute link. Instead of using the image:
 [image]

 It acted as if it was a relative link:

```
C:\path\to\html\email\http://example.com/image.png
```

As you can see, the image isn't showing up right. This is the code:

```
<img src=3D"http://example.com/image.png" style=3D"border:0" />
```

Comment: Where did the `3D` bits come from? That is not valid HTML

Comment: It came from the email. I don't know why. I could change it if necassary. I also wondered why it came with the email.